# Gradle: how to move outputs of a task?

Tags: gradle

I have set `buildDir` in build.gradle and all but one plugins honor that setting. For the one that insists on creating `build/reports/license/` and placing its outputs there, I'd like to move these files to my `${buildDir}`.

I tried adding a `doLast` block to the task

```
downloadLicenses {
    // ...
    doLast {
        file("build/reports/license").renameTo("${buildDir}/reports");
    }
}
```

but Gradle complains

> Could not find method doLast() for arguments [build_3s5ts0z1u2ed2z2xpd2pa56i$_run_closure50$_closure144@4d98efa4] on root project 'myProject'.

What am I missing here and how can I move the files after the task is done?

Edit: The plugin in question is [License Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin), and I did [report this as a bug](https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin/issues/127). I am hoping for a workaround until this is officially fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which plugin is this?

Try the following

```
println downloadLicenses.class.name
```

Is that printing the name of a task? I'm guessing there's an extension object named `downloadLicenses` rather than a task

Assuming there's a `downloadLicenses` task which is "hidden" by `downloadLicenses` extension object, this should work

```
tasks.getByName('downloadLicenses').doLast { ... }
```

If the "build" directory is hard-coded you should raise an issue with the plugin's author

Comment: Thanks, putting `tasks.getByName('downloadLicenses')` in front of my `doLast` block within `downloadLicenses` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have understood your question, but, if you would like to move your file to ${buildDir}/reports I think this should be your `doLast` block:

```
doLast {
    file("build/reports/license").renameTo(file("${buildDir}/reports"));
}
```

I hope I am helping you!

Comment: Well, yes, that's what I thought, too, but that gets me the above error.

Comment: Do you receive the same error even with file before the second path? Because in your first post there wasn't.

Comment: Yes, I do... if it was about the `file(...)` the error would probably be very different. Gradle does not like the `doLast`.